# Refresh image cache in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have an imageView from which I take visible part of image with `getDrawingCache()`. It works well. But when I change image in imageView and try to get bitmap from it, `getDrawingCache()` returns bitmap of the first image. I tried to call this method `buildDrawingCache()` before calling `getDrawingCache()` but it didn't help.

How can I refresh cache or associated bitmap or I don`t know what in order to get new image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was very simple:

```
   imageView.destroyDrawingCache();
   imageView.buildDrawingCache();
   imageView.getDrawingCache();
```